# Загрузка файла на сервер Sharepoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, requests

Пытаюсь загрузить файл на сервер Sharepoint через REST API, используя библиотеку Requests:

```
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        request_url = urljoin(host, f"_api/web/GetFolderById('{folder_id}')/Files/add(url='{file_name}',overwrite=true)")
        response = requests.post(request_url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password), data=file, headers=headers)
```

При загрузке файла все время получаю ошибку:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))
```

При этом, если загружать файл следующим образом, все работает:

```
response = requests.post(request_url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password), data=file.read(), headers=headers)
```

Получается, если прочитать файл в память целиком, то он успешно отправляется. Но, если использовать итератор, как это [показано в документации](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads), то все летит в тартарары. В чем может быть проблема: в моих кривых руках или Sharepoint-е? Или может есть какие-то особенности в работе данного функционала...

Comment: Файлы так загружаются: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: Я знаю об этом способе, но для ШП он не подходи: тогда заголовки записываются в файл и портят его. https://prnt.sc/utjnvx

Comment: В документации для ШП сказано, что данные идут в теле сообщения и не нужно использовать Multipart-Encoded. https://prnt.sc/utjpjb

Comment: Сам сервер разорвал подключение при первом случае: `Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение`. Возможно, сервер не умеет по частям получать файлы. Думаю, там используется эта вещь: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding